# Почему карточки в RecyclerView с большим отступом после первой прокрутки

Tags: android, recyclerview, margin, padding

Есть активити:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Есть фрагмент:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:listitem="@layout/first" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И есть карточки (в примере покажу одну, остальные такие же, просто где-то нет, например, картинки):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12px"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:strokeWidth="1px"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="194dp"
                android:contentDescription="desc"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Awesome title"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Awesome subtitle"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

При первом запуске карточки идут друг за другом, пока не прокрутишь вниз. После прокрутки вниз, до последней карточки, а потом вверх, между карточками появляется гигантский отступ. В чём может быть проблема?
Фрагмент в активити добавляю так:

```
val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val fragmentTest = MainFragment(service.getCards(receivedModels))
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragmentTest)
        ft.commit()
```

На скриншотах показано странное поведение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class MainFragment(val cards : MutableList<AbstractCard>) : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: CardAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        adapter = CardAdapter()
        binding.items.adapter = adapter
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.items.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = adapter
        }
        adapter.submitList(cards)
    }
}
```

Код фрагмента

Comment: покажите как объявляете в фрагменте список

Comment: @Andrew отредактировала вопрос. Там код фрагмента :)

Comment: у карточки   android:layout_height="match_parent" заменить на wrap_content

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло! :)